# Implement a Prolog program to verify whether primitive expressions are type-correct

Tags: prolog

Input format:

The first term in the rule is a list of lists, each sub-list being of the form `[<variable>, <type>]`.

The second term is a list whose elements are the terms in an expression. To avoid confusion with regards to precedence, the expression is assumed to have already been parsed, and the input expression is assumed to be in polish notation.

Output format:
`true` if the provided expression type checks successfully,false otherwise.

Samples:

Test Case 1:

```
?- is_correct([['int','x'],['int','y']],['&&','<','2','3','>','x','y']).
```

Output= TRUE

This is Polish notation which could also be implemented as

```
is_correct([['int','x'],['int','y']],['(','2','<','3',')','&&','(','x','>','y',')']).
```

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: I am new to prolog hence I am not able to understand how to proceed.

Comment: Basically I am trying to implement using stack but I am not able to understand how to go about it.

Comment: Notice also that you can omit most of the `'` you are using. Just write down the atoms: `[[int,x],[int,y]],[&&,<,...]]`.

Comment: Will that make any difference?

Comment: '2' is actually *very* different than 2, while 'x' is just noisy...

Comment: Both the atom `'2'` and the integer `2` fulfill the built-in predicate `atomic/1`: Make up your mind which representation fits best to the problem at hand. I suggest using integers in combination with [tag:clpfd].

Comment: There is no constraint on whether I can use quotes or not. What should I do further? I have devised a logic but being new to prolog I am not able to implement it.

Comment: What I plan to do is use the second way without polish notation one. First I want to extract the first element of first list which will be ['int','x'], Then I will check the type. If the type is int , I want to implement something which changes the value of x to 1. and use it in the next expression.

Comment: For next expression , I plan to parse each character. If i obtain an operator , I plan to check for both left and right sides of the expression, If both are numbers, I would check their type. and proceed in recursion. CAn anyone help me formulise a code for it??